# how to store objects value in var?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object, store

am try to understand a basic notion in JavaScript.

If somebody has some clarification.

if i has this.

```
//example: i have storing a default permanente array value with a constructor in: $gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default = [10,5]; 
console.log($gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default); // return me [10,5]; is nice

//now in a context, i need to store this value in temps var to do some stuff
var test = $gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default;
console.log(test): // return me [10,5]; is nice

// but after, if i do 
test[0]++;
// or
test[0]+=1;

console.log(test[0]); // return me 11 ( is ok ) !
//But why 
console.log($gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default) // return me 11 ??????
// why test[0]++; or test[0]+=1; increase my objets $gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default ???
// why increase my var test[0] increase $gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default[0] in same time ?
```

thanks a lot for help me

Comment: Because your `test` variable is a reference to `$gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default` meaning when you change `test`, `$gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default` updates to the same value.

If you'd like to change the reference to being a unique object, one tactic you could use is `Object.assign`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: I believe OP is saying that (by reference) `console.log(test)` is giving 11, which would indeed be odd..

Comment: @Geert-Jan - not really because both of those calls (test[0]++ and text[0+=1]) are incrementing the zero index of `test` which is the zero reference to `$gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default`

Comment: $gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default; // need to be static (alway [10,5])

Comment: @iamjpg: sure but then this should hold `test = $gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default =  [11,5]`, instead of `5` as OP says. But perhaps I'm reading too much in to it.

Comment: x = Object.assign({},$gameSystem.huds.hudsSlot.default)  is work thanks , but what about performance in MS ?